# How to create an .app File in Xcode for an command line tool programm

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

For normal cocoa applications it's easy to create an .app file. But what do i have to do to create an .app file from an command line project. I know that it usually doesn't make sense to create an .app from an command line tool, but in this case im using GLFW (an OpenGL lib) to create an Window. Or what would be the correct way to set up an c/c++ project and create an .app file from that project?

I hope you do understand what i mean, if not please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, there is no difference between command-line programs and application executables--there is only one kind of executable.  This is the same way other Unix systems like Linux work, but different from Windows.  OS X "application bundles" are just a certain way of packaging up an executable with related resources in a directory tree.

The easiest way to create a application that uses GLFW in Xcode is to create a Cocoa application project, then delete all references to Cocoa from the target.  Delete the reference to the Cocoa framework, delete all the source code the template created, delete the `MainMenu.xib`, et cetera.  You will need to leave the `Info.plist` intact as this is an essential part of OS X application bundles.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is not as unreasonable as you think, `.app` is just a special kind of ***"bundle"*** on OS X.

You can easily package this up yourself, but you need to know the proper file structure. In fact, virtually all the software I write for OS X is actually done this way; I am not a fan of the Xcode IDE.

Here is a [general overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html). The `Info.plist` file is the most important thing to focus on.

Comment: Thanks as well, as your way would have also worked and i will definetly take a closer look at bundels, since i'm also not a fan of xcode. A bit off topic but what editor do you use?

Comment: @BastianSeeleib: vim, surprisingly Apple keeps it pretty up-to-date with each new release of OS X. Emacs, on the other hand, they do not seem to care for ;)

Comment: The way I normally reverse engineered how to build certain types of bundles (frameworks, kexts, etc) was to create a project of the type in Xcode, without putting any code in it. Then build it with xcodebuild from the command line, and look at the commands executed during the build. From that, you can create a makefile with the right dependencies that executes equivalent commands. It takes a little effort the first time, but once you got it you can easily reuse it. It's totally worth it if you dislike Xcode as much as I do...